# Debería encerrar esto entre paréntesis?

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta con varias condiciones. y dos de ellas van unidas, de momento lo he puesto sin paréntesis y funciona pero no se si en un futuro me dará error por que no significa lo mismo.

la consulta en cuestión es esta:

```
SELECT * FROM `Articulos` WHERE `borrado` != 1 AND `sexo`= 1 AND `material` = 5 AND  FIND_IN_SET ('199', `empresa`) OR `Empresa` = '' ORDER BY `empresa` DESC
```

la condición que entiendo que va junta es `FIND_IN_SET ('199',`empresa`) OR`Empresa`= ''` que la idea es que si existe 199 en empresa o empresa esta vacío se ejecute.

Empresa es un campo con valores separados por coma.

¿El no tener metido en un paréntesis eso podría chocarme con el resto de condiciones? En caso que si sea necesario poner el paréntesis ¿cual seria la sintaxis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> la condición que entiendo que va junta es FIND_IN_SET ('199',empresa) OR Empresa= '' que la idea es que si existe 199 en empresa o empresa esta vacío se ejecute.

Según la descripción que das de lo que quieres que haga tu consulta, entonces sí, necesitas agregarle paréntesis. Toma en cuenta que los operadores `AND` tienen mayor precedencia que los operadores `OR`, por lo que sin paréntesis adicionales, tu consulta equivale a lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Articulos` 
WHERE (`borrado` != 1
       AND `sexo`= 1
       AND `material` = 5
       AND  FIND_IN_SET ('199', `empresa`)
      )
OR `Empresa` = '' 
ORDER BY `empresa` DESC
```

Para evitar esto, debes agregar paréntesis alrededor de las últimas 2 condiciones juntadas por el `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Articulos` 
WHERE `borrado` != 1
  AND `sexo`= 1
  AND `material` = 5
  AND  (FIND_IN_SET ('199', `empresa`) OR `Empresa` = '')
ORDER BY `empresa` DESC
```

Comment: Algo me decía que eso tenia que meterlo entre paréntesis :) Mil gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo he corregido